# Is there a clear, objective difference between intelligence in the arts and the sciences?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, intelligence, philosophy-of-psychology

Often, when referring to whether or not person A is "smart", discussion about Person A's political stance or their appreciation—or not—of art becomes part of the conversation.

This leads me to wonder; can a person with a wide range of interests and talents, including in the arts, still have strong curiosity, yet be unintelligent when it comes to mathematics and science?

Comment: Some people are just not into math, or sciences. Their brain is not wired for it.  They can very much be great at something else, though, like in art or in another activity not based on math, eg intuitive psychology or music or creative writing.

Comment: one does learn mathematics, and while STM memory and the like have a role to play in math they also do in the arts. limiting intelligence to math is not helpful, even supposing that maths is the most "difficult" subject to excel in (though i think i read that philosophical excellence is more strongly correlated with iq than any other subject)

Comment: One clear difference is that skill in math and science is easier to objectively measure than with the arts.  Skill is not the same as intelligence, but there is a relationship between them.

Answer (score 3):

> **Wikipedia**: Intelligence has been defined in many ways: the capacity for
> abstraction, logic, understanding, self-awareness, learning, emotional
> knowledge, reasoning, planning, creativity, critical thinking, and
> problem-solving. It can be described as the ability to perceive or
> infer information; and to retain it as knowledge to be applied to
> adaptive behaviors **within an environment or context**.

Arts and science are different contexts. You could then say that people have different "levels" of intelligence in these two different contexts.

As far as the difference between intelligence in the arts and the sciences - going by definition - it seems that this difference lies in the way the information is perceived. In sciences the information is generally perceived as a serialized stream of thoughts and in arts - generally - in a non-serialized or condensed way: emotions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, according to Harvardian Howard Gardner and [Multiple Intelligence Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_multiple_intelligences) (MI theory), is yes. There are criteria for separating intelligences. From the Wikipedia article:

> - potential for brain isolation by brain damage
> - place in evolutionary history
> - presence of core operations
> - susceptibility to encoding (symbolic expression)
> - a distinct developmental progression
> - the existence of savants, prodigies and other exceptional people
> - support from experimental psychology
> - support from psychometric findings

Thus, the parts of the brain and mind that are devoted to logical and scientific intelligence are distinct from those devoted to aesthetics and the fine arts. It should be noted that classical methods of providing empirical support are thin for this view of intelligence. MI theory is very much suitable for understanding how abilities come from the [modularity of the mind (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modularity-mind/) and is aligned intellectually with [faculty psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faculty_psychology). Besides Gardner, other prominent names in this area of philosophy of mind are [Marvin Minsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_Minsky) who wrote [*The Society of Mind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_of_Mind) and [Jerry Fodor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Fodor) who has written a number of philosophy books on the topic.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks! Always nice to bump into Larry Wall fans.

Comment: ... in MI theory I don't see explicitly the differentiation that is is made in the question, anyway.

Comment: @IoannisPaizis If you explicate your difficulties in more detail, I can address them.

Comment: In the link, in the eight sets of abilities I did not find "art" and "science" stated explicitly as two of these sets.

Comment: @IoannisPaizis That's very literal of you. Science and art are broad intelligences composed of more foundational intelligences. For instance, science draws heavily on domain-specific grammars that require linguistic and logical- mathematical intelligence. Science is a heavily epistemological practice that firms up justification with a specific ontology as given by philosophy of science such as 'hypothesis', 'IBE', 'falsification', 'empirical', etc. In this sense,  intelligence contains a very specific crystalized at of components...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_and_crystallized_intelligence?wprov=sfla1 for a simple dichotomy of intelligence... also see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-how/ for distinctions of crystallized intelligence as Know-how and Know-that.

Comment: Art draws on a different set of foundational intelligences such as aesthetics in contradistinction to epistemology, spatial-intelligence as opposed to logical- mathematical etc.

Comment: In MI theory, intelligence is seen as a plethora of domain-specific competencies. This works bc there is no one 'science' or 'art'. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_problem?wprov=sfla1 to dispel the notion that 'science' is a monolithic entity given in terms of necessity and sufficiency of criteria. Given your narrow interpretation of 'science' see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_resemblance?wprov=sfla1

Comment: If you have any questions about those articles, hit me up.

Answer (score 1):

> can a person with a wide range of interests and with real curiosity, be unintelligent when it comes to mathematics and science?

A person with a wide range of interests and curiosity can certainly have lower aptitude for mathematics, or less base knowledge about science from which to theorize, or can have less developed skills and knowledge in *any* particular field. Whether either amounts to *unintelligence* in the field depends on your definition of intelligence.